# Destroying a double threaded binary tree

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

So we have been asked to implement double threaded binary tree. They give us the function declarations and structures involved and we're supposed to give the function definitions.

The structure of a node of binary tree:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int rightThread;
    int leftThread;
} Node;
```

The tree structure:

```
typedef struct tree
{
    Node *root;
} Tree;
```

Now i don't know why they ask us to implement this using two structures (one for tree and one for node) but we cannot change these.

I have so far managed to insert nodes into the threaded tree, etc, etc but am having trouble with destroying the tree

We have been asked to implement it in the following way:

```
void tree_destroy(Tree *tree);
{
   //TODO
}

void destroy(Node *r)
{
    //TODO
}
```

I have implemented it as follows:

```
void destroy(Node *r)
{

    if(r==NULL)
        return;
   {
    destroy(r->left);
    destroy(r->right);
    }
    free(r);
}

void tree_destroy(Tree *t)
{
    if(t->root==NULL) return;
    destroy(t->root);
    free(t);
}
```

But there seems to be some problem with my code because there is a segmentation fault. Can someone please help me spot it OR have another way to implement the given functions?

EDIT:

The main function call:

```
Tree my_tree;
tree_initialize(&my_tree);
.
.
.
tree_destroy(&my_tree);
```

The function `tree_initialize`:

```
void tree_initialize(Tree *tree)
{
    tree->root=NULL;
}
```

When i have to add a new node to the tree, i initialize it in the following way:

```
Node* newnode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
newnode->data=data;
newnode->left=newnode->right=NULL;
newnode->rightThread=newnode->leftThread=1;
```

Comment: `if(t->root==NULL) return;` - I can only see - what if `t` is `NULL`? You have to show the code that allocates the tree. Please add all the code, a shortest example possible, that is compilable and when run allows to reproduce the error you are seeing. An error can be and most probably is in the code you are not showing. Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that others can copy to their own computers, compile and run and get the same problem.

Comment: still does not clear the segmentation error

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't think there is a shorter version of the code that i can add which will still work...

Comment: Could you show how it is being used? I.e. your main function.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of using threaded binary trees to get rid of recursion?

Comment: You are attempting to free the non-heap variable `my_tree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `free(t);` in `tree_destroy` is the problem: `tree_initialize` doesn't allocates `struct tree`, so `tree_destroy` should not free it.

Prototypes of the function `tree_initialize` assumes and the code

```
Tree my_tree;
tree_initialize(&my_tree);
.
.
.
tree_destroy(&my_tree);
```

makes `my_tree` to be stack, not heap variable and it could not and should not be free'd.

However, there is an approach to make `Tree` structure to be heap variable. In this case `tree_initialize` should looks like

```
Tree *tree_initialize()
{
    Tree tree = malloc (sizeof(tree));
    if (!tree) return NULL;
    tree->root=NULL;
    return tree;
}
```

and your initial `tree_destroy` containing `free` for Tree would be proper solution, but `main` should calls them like this:

```
Tree *my_tree = tree_initialize();
if (!my_tree) /* ERROR */
.
.
.
tree_destroy(my_tree);
```

Please note the extra checks for malloc fails in `Tree` allocation in `tree_initialize` and `main` and absence of `&` in `tree_destroy` call as well as in other functions like `tree_insert` and `tree_delete` using `Tree *` as an argument..